# ReactJs, must it use render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I have a general question about how ReactJs `Render()` functionality. Say we have some HTML within index.html

```
<section id="Hello">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>Something something Darkside</p>
</section>
```

And a react Class

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Can we pass the contents of the `#Hello` into the react class to render, instead of writing JSX?

And also, is it possible to have this, in the index.html source

```
<Hello>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>Something something Darkside</p>
</Hello>
```

and automatically connect it to a React Class

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Here `<Hello />` connects to the class automatically?

This would be similar to Angulars `<ng-content />` and initialisation of objects

Comment: Is your goal in the first question solely to have react render the #Hello html without using jsx?

Comment: Pretty much that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal in the first question solely to have react render the #Hello html without using jsx then you will need to use the plain JavaScript REACT syntax.

Something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id='container'></div>

    <script>
        var Hello = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            return React.createElement(
                'section',
                { id: 'Hello' },
                React.createElement('h1',null, 'Hello world'),
                React.createElement('p',null,'Something something Darkside')
            );
          }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Hello,null),document.getElementById('container'));
    </script>
</body>
```

if you like you can use something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to generate plain javascript from jsx for you. they have an interactive tool [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3Csection%20id%3D%22Hello%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EHello%20world%3C%2Fh1%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3ESomething%20something%20Darkside%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fsection%3E) where you can try it out.

---

For your question "Can the ReactDOM.render read the children properties of html within the index.html?". 
Assuming you are asking if you can just have ReactDOM.render return the html of #Hello. The answer is no you cannot.

ReactDOM.render method expects you to return a *ReactComponent*

So something like this would be invalid:

```
<section id="Hello">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>Something something Darkside</p>
</section>

<script>
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return $('#Hello').html(); //<-- Error here
  }
});
</script>
```

gives an error:

> A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned
>   undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run the code snippet to test yet but based on my knowledge. You can do something like:

```
<Hello id='hello-id'></Hello>
<script type='text/babel'>
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <p>Something something Darkside</p>
    </Hello>,
    document.getElementById('hello-id')
);
</script>
```

Result should be:

```
<Hello id='hello-id'>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <p>Something something Darkside</p>
    </div>
</Hello>
```

`this.props.children` ([Children props](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html)) can be used to pass the children elements onto react component.
The `Hello` in `ReactDOM.render` is connected to the `Hello` class. But `<Hello/>` in the html source is not. It's just the custom html tag.

Comment: Can the ReactDOM.render read the children properties of html within the index.html?